# How can I re-enter Italy if I lost my Permesso di Soggiorno receipt?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, italy, italian-residents

I am currently in Ghana and I have lost my Permesso di Soggiorno receipt. What do I need to do to reenter Italy to get another Permesso from Police Headquarters?

I have worked with agencies in Reggio Emilia in the past years. I have with me my Carta di identità that is still valid me and my Codice fiscale, a copy of my Permesso di Soggiorno and copies of my CUD from 2011 to 2014. My Carta di identità will expire this year in December 2019.

I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: I think your best bet is to approach the Italian consulate or embassy and see if they can give you a visa to travel to Italy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment... I will.

Comment: @phoog want to turn into an answer for future users?